# Touchpad driver corrupted, no Windows 10 version

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10, drivers, touchpad, lenovo-laptop

So I have a Lenovo G50-70, and my touchpad stopped working, and when I went to the solution center it said that a driver is missing (it doesn't know which one though, go figure), so I'm pretty sure this is my touchpad driver.

I recently downloaded Windows 10 and when I looked for the driver on Lenovo's website, they only had the option for Windows 8.1, not Windows 10. So I downloaded it and at the very end it said that the driver couldn't be installed because it is for windows 8.1 and using it might cause a loss of memory or some other type of damage.

I'm at a loss here, what should I do? I could downgrade back to Windows 8.1, but it is godawful. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Your only real option, since you don't want to revert back to Windows 8.1 is to wait until a driver which supports Windows 10 is released for the touchpad device

Comment: Of course [Synaptics](http://www.synaptics.com/en/drivers.php) has a Windows 10 compatible driver published on their website.  You will lose Lenovo specific features, of course, the deice doesn't work on Windows 10 without drivers so that might be an acceptable trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

Determine the touchpad manufacturer and contact them directly for a Windows 10 compatible driver.

If they and Lenovo can't provide one, then your notebook is, for all intents and purposes, not fully Windows 10 compatible.

The touchpad manufacturer and/or Lenovo may update the driver at some point to support Win10, but who knows if/when that'll actually happen.

A possible solution/work-around: use an external mouse.

Answer (score 0):

unisntall your old driver first then try check at windows update

if it doesn't install your driver, you have to go with windows 8.1 driver

using windows 8.1 driver on windows 10 is fine, just ignore that message